# Allowing a popup to bleed off the map

Tags: leaflet

By default, popups on a Leaflet map are constrained to the outlines of the map itself.  My UI guy wants the popups to bleed off over the surrounding page.

Is this even a possibility?  All suggestions welcome.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, my company pulled me off the project all together.